# Angular Testing Mock Http-Service

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test for angular app. I want to mock the Value coming from a service for http-calls.

**component.spec.ts**

```js
let apiService: ApiService;
let mockedHttpClient: HttpClient = mock(HttpClient);

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [EditorComponent],
    providers: [
      { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiService },
      {
        provide: HttpClient,
        useFactory: () => instance(mockedHttpClient),
      },
    ],
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  apiService = TestBed.inject(ApiService);

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it("should get Informations", (done: DoneFn) => {
  component.id = "id1";
  spyOn(apiService, "getInfosById").and.returnValue(of(infos));

  component.getInformations();

  expect(component.infos).toEqual(infos);
});
```

**component.ts**

```
private readonly unsubscribe = new Subject();

getInformations() {
   this.apiService
      .getInfos(this.id)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.infos = data;
   })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

**api-service.ts**

```
public getInfos(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<Infos>(
              this.apiUrl +'infos/' + id,
              httpOptions)}
```

I want to mock the function above.

**Error**

```
<spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getInformations()
```

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better Way to mock a http-Service with .pipe and .subscribe?

Comment: in your ts method name is getInfos () and you are spying on getInfosById(), and  what is productInfos? you have to mock that too.
``` 
    spyOn(apiService, 'getInfos').and.returnValue(of(infos));

```

Comment: `it("should get Informations", (done: DoneFn) => {
  const infos = "mockvalue"
  component.id = "id1"
  spyOn(apiService, 'getInfos').and.returnValue(of(infos));

  component.getInformations();

  expect(component.getInfos).toEqual(productInfos);  
})`

Comment: The getInfosById is from an extra http service file. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: It is always better to use tooling Angular provides us with instead of trying does the same things ourselves: https://itnext.io/testing-angular-http-communication-9a120a10da18

Comment: Why not use the `HttpTestingController` provided by Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in order to mock the response of the HTTP Call:

```
@Injectable()
class MockApiService extends ApiService {
  getInfos(): any {
     const data = {} // Fill the object as per how the response comes
     return data;
  }
}

beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [EditorComponent],
          providers: [
             <!------- You need to add the below line -----!>
            { provide: ApiService, useClass: MockApiService },
            {
              provide: HttpClient,
              useFactory: () => instance(mockedHttpClient),
    
            },    
          ],
          imports: [
            HttpClientModule
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      });

it('should run #getInformations() method in component', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'getInformations').and.callThrough();
  component.getInformations();
  expect(component.getInformations).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

// THe above test case will cover the success scenario of the service call
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the answers. I could solve my Problem, but now i want to get further. I dont want to test http itself (have done that already), i just want to mock the restult of a service. It works fine for one method, but if i do more than one, it doesn't.

```
fit("should get getDesignerInformations", (done: DoneFn) => {


    spyOn(apiService1,'getInfo').and.returnValue(of(infoMock)); <-- this one works
    spyOn(apiService2, 'getProduct').and.returnValue(of(productMock));<-- this one doesn't work
}
```

The first call get mocked, but the second doesn't exist after first one called.